# Resultados de um calculo de média incoerente

Tags: javascript, dom

Em um exercício pedi para calcular a media das notas,entretanto na hora de mostrar aparece um valor completamente fora da logica

**Script**

```
   function cadastrarUsuario() {


        let nome = document.querySelector("#nome").value;
        let nota1 = document.querySelector("#nota1").value;
        let nota2 = document.querySelector("#nota2").value;
        let nota3 = document.querySelector("#nota3").value;
        getAprovado(nota1, nota2, nota3);
        criarUsuarioTable(nome,nota1,nota2,nota3)

    }

    function getAprovado(nota1, nota2, nota3) {

        console.log('numero um ',nota1)
        console.log('numero dois ',nota2)
        console.log('numero tres ',nota3)
        let media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;


        if (media >= 7) {
            alert('Aprovado')
        } else {
            alert('Reprovado')
        }
    }

    function criarUsuarioTable(nome,nota1,nota2,nota3){

       let html =  document.querySelector("#tabela");

       html.innerHTML =
       `
       <tr>
            <td>${nome}</td>
            <td>${nota1}</td>  
            <td>${nota2}</td>  
            <td>${nota3}</td>  
            <td>${(nota1+nota2+nota3)/3}</td>    

       </tr>

       `
    }

</script>
```

**Console**

*Felipe Machado Da Silva    5   9   10  1970*

Comment: Tanto a maneira dentro do template string da media,quanto o da variável estão dando o valor "louco"

Answer (score 1):

Todos os dados vindo de um formulário vem como formato texto,ou seja é necessário a conversão,utilizando o **parseInt**

```
        nota1 = parseInt(nota1);
        nota2 = parseInt(nota2);
        nota3 = parseInt(nota3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente exibir a `variavel` 'media' em vez de repetir a expressão do cálculo na `tabela`